# PHP - Website loading because of file size

Tags: php, file-upload

I am making a basic website where you can sign up and login. Everything is working fine, except for uploading an image file to use as a profile picture. Whenever the file is around 300+ MB and I submit the form, the page keeps loading and eventually gives me

> '502: Bad Gateway'

as an error.

I already tried changing the `max_file_size` in my `php.ini`, but this did not change anything. I also tried increasing the `memory_limit` in the `php.ini`, but again, this did not fix my problem

**EDIT 1:**
I am getting the

> 502: Bad Gateway

error still whenever I use PhpStorm. When I am uploading it my NAS (which has PhpMyAdmin and Apache installed) everything works good from there. I changed the settings in my php.ini, but this did not give me any other result.

**EDIT 2:**
The post was edited and said that it has been answered already, but this is not the case. I am still having the same problem.

**EDIT 3:**
The problem has been solved. It was due to the security that was setup on my NAS. Changing the settings here and there solved the issue.

Comment: image is around 300+ MB??

Comment: What do you mean by profile image of 300+ mb?

Comment: FYI, I removed the `phpstorm` tag since your IDE has nothing to do with your issue. Both `login` and `account` should probably be changed to `upload` instead.

Comment: try using php's ftp instead.

Comment: if you're running this off of local, did you restart everything after making those changes? are you also present in your question?

Comment: Allowing users to upload 300MB images is a very bad idea for several reasons. 1. If the image isn't resized, every time the image is shown, the users will literally download 300MB. 2. If the image _is_ resized, it will take a lot amount of memory and server resources to do it.

Comment: Sorry, but I was meant to say 300KB, instead of 300MB

Answer (score 1):

In php.ini you need to set both of the following values:

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size=300M

; ... more ini stuff...

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=300M
```

That should fix your uploading probelm.

Comment: They're trying to upload a 300M+ file here and we don't know what they're using neither. 128M will fail. Edit: I see you edited. This comment as per original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45306187/1

Comment: I just copied and pasted out of my local php.ini file, thinking that he could pick up on the fact that those values needed to be changed. But I changed them just in case.

Comment: Plus, for most users, you will most likely need to add onto the max execution time as well.

Comment: I edited my above comment. @GeorgeShaw

Comment: This is not the fix to my problem. I think it is a PhpStorm issue, because I am not getting this problem when I upload the files to my NAS webserver and open the page from there.